# Connection timeout over ssl

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, connection-timeout

I have an client application that connects to a remote server via https for commercial purposes. This connection is using old IO (blocking connection). It normally runs smoothly.

Recently I have cloned the client thus created a new client instance, running from the same box and using the same client certificate. I'm noticing many connection timeouts from the server. I wonder if the cloning may have somehow been the cause of the timeouts and if there is a ssl issue here.

Both instances receive the following system parameters for security:

```
    javax.net.ssl.trustStore=cacerts
    javax.net.ssl.keyStore=1234567890123
    javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=wordpass
```

Unfortunately the support from the server side is quite limited. I hope someone in this forum may come up with an idea.

Comment: Is the original client still in use and does it show the same time-outs? May be the server traffic just increased and now overloads the server.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Indeed both clients are used and both fail to connect with timeouts. I stopped the clone's work but the server kept rejecting the original client's requests for four hours. Then it recovered. As I said the server side support is not very helpful...